# PyTorch - Computing and printing the training accuracy of the QuickStart Tutorial

Tags: python, pytorch

to learn PyTorch, I started with the [Quickstart Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html). In the **train()** method, I noticed that `they don't print the training accuracy during the training session`. Only the training loss is printed.

Coming from Keras, this was very unusual for me, since the training accuracy automatically printed when you call fit().

So, I decided to modify the tutorial code like the following to print the training accuracy:

```
def train(dataloader, model, optimizer, loss_fn):

  model.train()
  size = len(dataloader.dataset)
  num_batches = len(dataloader)

  training_loss = 0.0
  correct = 0.0

  for batch, (imgs, labels) in enumerate(dataloader):
    imgs = imgs.to(device=device)
    labels = labels.to(device=device)

    predictions = model(imgs)
    loss = loss_fn(predictions, labels)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    # accumulate the training loss - each batch's loss will be added to trainin_loss
    training_loss += loss.item()
    
    # determines the number of correct predictions
    correct += (predictions.argmax(1) == labels).type(torch.float).sum().item()
  
  # end of for loop - all batches are processed      

  # after all batches are processed, determine the average training loss
  training_loss = training_loss / num_batches
  # this would be the training accuracy: number of correct predictions / number of samples in dataset
  correct = correct / size

  print(f"{datetime.datetime.now()} Training Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {training_loss:>8f} \n")
```

Is this ok ? As a beginner to PyTorch, I wanted to make sure that is correct before I start training my neural networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all looks correct. Doing things like this should not influence training. `loss.backward()` computes your gradients and anything not connect to that can not change them. By the way, just run the training, you can't break anything :) (Yet. Just wait when you start building self driving cars.).

I thought, in Keras/TensorFlow `fit()` does not compute *accuracy* automatically, you still have to specify this metric for example when *compiling* the model or as a parameter to `fit()`, e.g.:

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
```